# Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` resulted in a `400

Tags: php, ads, google-ads-api

[image: Error here]

PHP version : 7.4
GRPC installed

Comment: Hi @Rinki, welcome to SO! DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: There are more than few reasons you're getting this error but my first question would be have you obtained refresh token from Google and placed it in google_ads_php.ini config file?